# Need to autopopulate dates in certain columns/cells based on ultimate deadline

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks in advance for any help or advice on the best way to handle this. I've been doing this by hand for some time now but as I get more familiar with Google Sheets and Apps Script, etc. I'm hoping I can find a smarter way to handle this. In the screenshot below, I have a document that essentially has a list of courses that have to be attended and due dates next to them. What I'm looking to do is have an ultimate deadline listed in the top right (in this case I1), and then have this Deadline date calculate and fill the "Due Date" columns from left to right in their category (Express first, then Intermediate, then Advanced) with the dates they need to complete each task which should push them right up to the deadline... I know, I'm asking a lot... but it gets worse.

[image]

In this example, there are 19 courses and they have 16 days to complete, that should round up to an even number so that it assigns two courses for the same day, and then the next two courses for a different day, etc from left to right, in that category. So again, finished example should look something like this:

[image]

At the bottom there, I have some variables I'm keeping track of to use as needed for example, the number of courses, because I may need to add courses to each of the lists, and then I'd need the days to spread across any row that had a course item listed in B, E, H.... Maybe I should just do it by hand right? lol

EDIT: Adding a link to [read-only version of this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_a_-dO9xNN45XLV5rgDk2RhRgNxdUJZKBGc5qAD75OI/edit#gid=582106824)

Comment: How do you know when to start counting? Would the date lines move as days pass? (eg if you don't do anything for 2 days because something happened, should it automatically move the schedule?)

Comment: Also, could you please share a read-only version without the private information? Working with images is a pain.

Comment: @Martí I'm sorry those are very good questions. I added a read-only version of the document as requested by editing my post. I was thinking of it being initiated by one of two things either a button that I'd create and when that is clicked it looks at the Go Live Date and then calculates from today() whatever date that is, which I feel would be the best or when I add the Go Live Date in that box have that base it off the day that was entered/edited to adjust dates throughout. I do not need it to automatically change if nothing is done. I appreciate any help/guidance you have :)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to make sequence of the delta days to be added to today.

### Thought process

We want to start adding 0 days n times, then 1 day n times, then 2, and so on and so forth. An example would be something like

| B | E | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 |  |  |

Because the columns are not together, we'll work them desperately. The formula for this is:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  FLOOR(SEQUENCE(<quantity in group>; 1; <quantity in previous groups>)/<courses per day>)
)
```

For example in column `E` the formula would be:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  FLOOR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(E4:E23);1;COUNTA(B4:B23))/C27)
)
```

So now we add it to today:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  TODAY()+FLOOR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(E4:E23),1,COUNTA(B4:B23))/C27)
)
```

### Final formulas

For the `B` column:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  TODAY()+FLOOR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B4:B23);1;0)/C27)
)
```

For the `E` column:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  TODAY()+FLOOR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(E4:E23);1;COUNTA(B4:B23))/C27)
)
```

For the `H` column:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  TODAY()+FLOOR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(H4:H23);1;COUNTA(B4:B23,E4:E23))/C27)
)
```

### References

- [SEQUENCE (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
- [FLOOR (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093487)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: Does this solve your problem? Did I miss something?